# JPG to PBM image conversion

Tags: java, image, jpeg, image-conversion, pbm

I'm trying to convert a ".jpg" file to ".pbm" in java, but I've not been lucky, I tried with the following code: `javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image("image.jpg");
image.saveAs("imagepbm.pbm");`
But it didn't work, Could someone help me please! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Didn't work" is not sufficient. What error did you get? Does the JavaXT library support PBM format?  Have you checked?

Comment: *".... but I've not been lucky"* - What has luck got to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

In standard Java 8 PBM format is not supported.  The list of supported formats as returned by

```
    String[] f2 = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();
    Arrays.stream(f2).forEach(t -> System.out.println(t));
```

is:

```
JPG
jpg
bmp
BMP
gif
GIF
WBMP
png
PNG
wbmp
jpeg
JPEG
```

Comment: @haraldK javaxt uses ImageIO internally.